# Android onOverrideUrlLoading based on javascript return value

Tags: android, cordova, webview, android-webview, cordova-plugins

I am working on a hybrid app and trying to return true or false in onOverrideUrlLoading of webview based on returned value from javascript function executed in webview

Example code I have so far.

```
//Have a boolean variable isExternalDomain; 
//Added JavascriptInterface webView.addJavascriptInterface(this, "android");

public boolean onOverrideUrlLoading(final String url) {


WebView.loadUrl("javascript:android.onData('true')");

//I Tried inserting sleep, delay EG: Thread.sleep(200); 


//I see the delay but still javascript executes last.

if(isExternalDomain) {
 return true;
 } else {
 return false;
 }

}

@JavascriptInterface public void onData(String value)
 {   
 isExternalDomain = true; 
}
```

So the Issue I am having is javascript execution happens after onOverrideUrlLoading completed executing all lines with isExternalDomain as false. I would like to have onOverrideUrlLoading returning true or false based on javascript returned value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, running JavaScript code from inside `onOverrideUrlLoading()` isn't possible. You must return from `onOverrideUrlLoading()` before WebView can do anything else. When you call `WebView.loadUrl()` from inside `onOverrideUrlLoading()`, what really happens is an asynchronous task gets posted onto the WebView's message loop. It only gets processed after you leave `onOverrideUrlLoading()`. Thus, no amount of delay will make WebView to process your request while your code is inside `onOverrideUrlLoading()`.

If you want to prevent navigation from happening based on the decision made by JavaScript code, it's more natural to do that on the JavaScript side by using `window.onbeforeunload` event handler. If you return non-`null` value from it, an attempt to navigate away by clicking a link will be cancelled.

Below is a sample of JavaScript code:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    if (navigationDisallowed()) {
        return true;  // Prevent navigating away from the page.
    } else {
        return null;  // Allow navigating away.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mikhail, that helps. I was assuming the same but wanted to check with someone to confirm. Window.onbeforeunload doesn't work for me as its not supported on iOS and also I am trying to prevent default navigation for external domains done using javascript or link press to open them in inappbrowser. I guess using onbeforeunload I can get only the destination url if navigation is done using link click.  We moved the external domain validation to native side for android so problem solved (but needs an app store update everytime we need to whitelist a domain).

Comment: Glad it helped! Didn't know about the iOS limitation.